# Row-level-security based on relation table data

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase

I am getting into [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) and to practice I am **making a suuuper simplified website-builder**.
However I am having troubles with the row-level-security policies.

**I have three tables:**

- **user** → with users' information like first name, last name, etc.
- **website** → all websites
- **user_website** → Contains the information which website belongs to which person (since a website can be owned/editted by multiple users)

| user |
| --- |
| user_id |
| ... |

| website |
| --- |
| website_id |
| ... |

| user_website |
| --- |
| user_id |
| website_id |
| user_role |
| ... |

I didn't find any useful resource, because honestly I still lack the knowledge to know how to search properly for what I need.

I only found simple expressions like `(uid() = user_id)`, but since the "permissions" are stored in another table, I don't know how to access that.

I used queries like the following but it didn't work as intended:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user_website as uw
  JOIN website as w
  ON uw.website_id = w.website_id
WHERE
  uw.user_id = auth.uid()
```

Help is much appreciated – thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called a friend for help and he pointed out a [section in the Supabase docs about "policies with joins"](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#policies-with-joins) ... yet it still didn't work for me.

The reason was that the **RLS-policy on the table website references the table user-website**, which didn't allow users yet to access anything.

#### Solution

**RLS-policy for select on website:**

```
auth.uid() in (
  select user_id from user_website
  where website_id = website.website_id
)
```

**RLS-policy for select on user-website:**

```
auth.uid() = user_id
```

Comment: What helped me debug was a version of the policy where I simulated the response of the query:
`auth.uid() in ('2ce0b0af-baad-4a2d-83fe-c4c2ee9f2cbb','2ce0b0af-baad-4a2d-83fe-c4c2ee9f2caa')` (the first UUID being the one of the logged-in user, the second one a fake one)
And since that policy worked I knew it had to be something inside the _in ( ... )_

Answer (score 2):

You could define a policy like that:

```
CREATE POLICY may_edit ON website
   FOR UPDATE TO PUBLIC
   USING (EXISTS
             (SELECT 1 FROM user_website
              WHERE user_website.website_id = website.website_id
              AND user_website.user_id = uid()
             )
         );
```

Here, `uid()` is a function that returns your current user ID.

This policy will let everyone modify their own website.